# How to make a composed primary key using cloud firestore in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to use it in a small application. I'm used to work with relational db and it's weired for me the concept of document and collections of firebase because I didn't work with NoSql before.
I have a form which consists of `firstName`, `lastName`, `age`, `gender` and other attributes. I want to make a constraint that prohibit to enter two different users with the same `firstName` and `lastName`.
I choose the cloudfirestore for different reasons such as :

1. Offline support for iOS, Android, and web clients.
2. Indexed queries with compound sorting and filtering.
3. Atomic write and transaction operations.

as mentioned in [Choose a Database: Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) .

However in the cloudfirestore and under the tab `Rules` I have these lines:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add some validations or rules such as in the realtime database like [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Is there any sections that cover this part of validations rules in cloudfirestore that I missed? Any link or proposition will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no separate validation rules in Cloud Firestore. Instead you'll write the validation logic as part of the `write` rules.

See the section on [data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) in the Firebase documentation for more information, and some examples.